# Laravel Authenticate Passport using different table

Tags: php, laravel

I am using Laravel Passport for authentication.In my project I need to use table called travel instead of users table for authentication.For that I used the following in auth.php

> ```
> 'providers' => [
>     'users' => [
>         'driver' => 'eloquent',
>         'model' => App\Travel::class,
>     ],
> ```

This works fine If I call http://localhost:8000/api/oauth/token. I am getting token. But when I tried to use this auth in another api in routes ,it says "Route Login not defined"

> Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth:api'], 'as' => 'api'], 
>   function(){ Route::post('details', 'API\UserController@details');});

Route file.

```
Route::post('login', 'API\UserController@authenticate');
Route::post('register', 'API\UserController@register');
Route::post('getToken', 'API\UserController@gettoken');
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth:api'], 'as' => 'api'],  function(){
Route::post('details', 'API\UserController@details');    
});
```

Please help.

Regards,
Rekha

Comment: Do you have a route for `login`? Should look something like `Route::post("login", ...)->name("login");`. Please post your complete routes file, or the result of `php artisan route:list` into your question.

Comment: Route file code attached.pls check

Comment: You're missing `->name("login")`; When the error is `Route **login** not defined`, it means somewhere you have `route("login")`, but your route needs to be **named** in order to use it that way.

Comment: I have modified that and now i am getting another error,Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException: The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST. in file C:\wamp64\www\travel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\RouteCollection.php on line 256.<br>I am using post method